# How to get rid of space after header row when appending to csv file [python]?

Tags: python, csv, append, writer

I created a blank csv with some field names, and then have a script that calculates some values for each of those new fields/columns, and appends that row to the initially blank csv. I iterate through a folder of .csv files, and based on the data in those files, I create a new row of values for each iteration in the for loop, and then append those rows consecutively to the initially made .csv file. However, when I tried doing this, and then looking at the newly created .csv file, I saw that there was a space, a blank row, after each entry, so a space after the header row, and then a space after each newly appended row. I am using python for this.

I created the .csv file with this code:

```
fields = ['Field_1', 'Field_2', 'Field_3']

filename = 'final_results.csv'

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile: 
    # creating a csv writer object 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # writing the fields 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
```

In my script, I do calculations on the data from each of the .csv files I loop through. I ultimately compute a "Value_1", "Value_2", and a "Value_3", where "Value_1" should fall under "Field_1", "Value_2" should fall under "Field_2", and "Value_3" should fall under "Field_3". I then create a new row of these new values to be appended to my .csv file with simply:

```
new_row = [Value_1, Value_2, Value_3]
```

I then appended with this code:

```
with open('Final_results.csv', 'a') as f_object:
            writer_object = writer(f_object)
            writer_object.writerow(new_row)
            f_object.close()
```

This led to spaces after the header rows and then spaces after each consecutively added row when I looked at the "Final_results.csv", the final product.

I then tried this:

```
with open('Final_results.csv', 'a', newline="") as f_object:
            writer_object = writer(f_object)
            writer_object.writerow(new_row)
            f_object.close()
```

adding `newline=""`

And now when I look at "Final_results.csv", there are no spaces/blank rows between the newly appended rows, which is what I want, but there is still a blank row between the header row and the appended rows. How can I get rid of this space? I can't find what specific argument/parameter that would need to be added/changed within the "writer" module to address this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `newline=""` to the first "open", too?

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!